# how to write to the app.config

Tags: arduino, app-config

I have created a custom section in my appconfig, I basically want to store some settings that for a number of Arduino's that are connected, such as comp port settings, and an id number, I am monitoring when a device is plugged in and unplugged, so I would like to update the app.config accordingly, I can read them fine, and have set up a class to handle the reading and enumeration, i have also set the readonly attribute to false, so i can change the settings, but i cannot seem to save them ?

am i missing something simple ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "you can't save them"? Which language? Platform? What? app.config makes me think about .NET (then you simply have to make them user specific instead of application specific) but...

Comment: hi thanks for the response, sorry, it is written in C# .Net 4.5.1, ive added a save function in the configuration class, but it just doesn't save it to file, i don't get any errors. this is the way i have written it, and like i say, it reads fine. [link](http://www.itworld.com/development/392588/how-create-custom-configsection-aspnet-c)

Comment: VS will restore settings for each run. Moreover settings at application scope cannot be changed (only User settings can be). You change this inside .settings designer. For such simple task use .settings instead of a custom settings section (probably to begin it's much easier). To store multiple values you may use arrays.

Comment: am i wrong in assuming that the settings are a kvp ? as i say, each of my arduino's have multiple settings to be stored, and this may grow ? sorry, i have just never used the app.config before

Comment: it depends. if settings are something very simple then .settings are pretty easy to use. If you implemented a custom section you should also re-run your application OUTSIDE VisualStudio because for each build it'll overwrite app.config with default (empty) one.